# Unreal Macro blueprint to C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have some problems getting a macro in Unreal blueprint converted to C++. The macro influences a lot of my code, and in the picture included, the C++ code is not similar to the macro which the code is based on

[image: Unreal blueprint]

The code is based on this

[image: Macro code]

```
bool AGrid::TileValid(int Row, int Column)
{
    if (((Row >= 0) && (Row < NumRows)) && ((Column >= 0) && (Column<NumColumns)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any suggestion on how I can implement this code?

Comment: looks good to me! When you debug and you see it returning bad results, what are the values of  `Row`, `Column`, `NumRows`, and `NumColumns`, and what are expected vs actual results of the function?  Please include a [mre].

Comment: the values of 'Row' and 'Column' is set to 'NumRows' and 'NumColumns' to check if either of 'NumRows' and 'NumColums' is less then 0. This is to make sure the code still works. F.eks: 'if NumRows is less then 0, then this code is faulty' Sorry that this is not a minimal reproducible exsample, but this little code is just a check if either 'NumRows' and or 'NumColums' is less then 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure as to what exactly isn't working?

I'm going to take a guess and say that you were expecting your (what is now a C++ function, not a Macro) `TileValid` Node from C++ does not have the Execution pins that the Blueprint Macro has.

Make sure that you do not mark your `TileValid` function with `BlueprintPure`, instead mark it with `BlueprintCallable`. Also make sure that it isnt marked as a `const` function, this will also affect its appearance and functionality.

`BlueprintPure` and/or `const` C++ functions which are `BlueprintCallable` do not require direct execution (the white lines) and are instead executed for everytime their output pin is wired into another Node, they will then be executed when that parent Node is executed. This can change their behavior, as variables they may use can change in-between subsequent executions, thus potentially altering their output.

Answer (score 0):

This code did where both `UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, BlueprintPure)` in the callable H class. Removing the `BlueprintPure` from this code wold solve the executionable variable